# Tables in database are not creating in Databas after migrations and migrate in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a project with multiple apps. In one of the app  named as App1 I have an existing model in this app. I want a new model in this app. But the table of new model is not creating in the Database after applying migrations. Followings are the things I have tried:

I have deleted the file from migrations folder.

python manage.py makemigrations App1
python manage.py migrate --fake APP1 zero

but still table in Database of new model is not creating.

Comment: Is the table not created or not visible in `admin`. If it is the latter case, try adding the model in `admin.py`

Comment: I have add the model in admin.py when I click on it It give me error relation App1_modelname does not exist.

Comment: It means that table is not creating in Database

Comment: have you included your app_name in `installed_apps` in `settings.py`

Comment: YES I have included in Installed APP